# Partial match Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have Table A which contains only strings, or strings+numbers, in general the list is very inconsistent. I also have Table B which contains a list of the names I have to retrieve from Table A where there is a match or partial match. My issue is that sometimes my formula doesn't work.

As you can see in Column C the below formula works for all except for rows 5 and 8 because I want to retrieve "toro res" which is in my list (table B) and instead I have 0.

[image]

Comment: probably because your desired list contains "toro res", it does not identify the word "toro". Instead if you have just "toro" in your list, all of them will be recognised

Comment: You will need to create a 2 dimensional range, where you put the possible inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: yes, that is the main problem. For every inconsistent strings in the list where there is let's say "1x34toro - nap45596" I want to get back torores. I am not sure if this is feasible. So anything that look at the partial match and get back the outcome listed in my list.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated create a table with inputs in one column and output in another, then change the return of the formula to the output column:

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$5,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A2,"*" & $H$2:$H$5 & "*"),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try, I have thousands of rows to go through:) I appreciated your help!